NPM inject package into my package's dependency?
I have a project, that depends on library @keenmate/js-common-helpers (which I maintain). This library has dependency on svelte-spa-router.
I made a fork of library svelte-spa-router as @keenmate/svelte-spa-router, that I would like to tell the @keenmate/js-common-helpers to use, instead of the original dependency svelte-spa-router (A sort of a dependency-injection of @keenmate/svelte-spa-router into @keenmate/js-common-helpers).
I discovered, that NPM allows to "alias" a dependency, so I tried aliasing my package @keenmate/svelte-spa-router as svelte-spa-router:
npm i svelte-spa-router@npm:@keenmate/svelte-spa-router
Which did not work, because I found out, that the @keenmate/js-common-helpers has its own node_modules/ dir with its own svelte-spa-router/ copy which it probably references...
I also discovered an option ``, that I tried to use to no avail, like so:
"overrides": {
    "@keenmate/js-common-helpers": {
        "svelte-spa-router": "npm:@keenmate/svelte-spa-router@^1.0.5"
    }
}

Workaround:
Yes, I could change the @keenmate/js-common-helpers library since I have a direct influence over it and configure it to use @keenmate/svelte-spa-router... and I might just stick to it in the end as a workaround for now...
